# Flutter - How to load images in from assets correctly?

Tags: image, flutter, dart, asynchronous

So I have this code that loads images from assets, correctly:

```
ClipRRect getUserCard(int index) {
  double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
  return ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      //IMAGE (and Name Overlay)
      Container(
        width: screenWidth,
        height: screenHeight,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage(lstUsers[index]["imageUrl"][0]),
              fit: BoxFit.cover),
        ),
        //NAME OVERLAY
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            //NAME AND AGE
            Container(
              //alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: 80,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                //borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        lstUsers[index]["name"] + ", ",
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 24,
                        ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        lstUsers[index]["age"],
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 20,
                        ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Text(
                    lstUsers[index]["profession"],
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            const Divider(),
            //SWIPE BUTTONS
            Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
              FloatingActionButton(
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.close_outlined,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  size: 32,
                ),
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    cardController.triggerLeft();
                  });
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 25,
              ),
              FloatingActionButton(
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.favorite_border_outlined,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  size: 32,
                ),
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    cardController.triggerRight();
                  });
                },
              ),
            ]),
            const Divider(),
          ],
        ),
        //),
      ),
      // ),
      ],
    ),
   );
 }
```

However, this causes the app to crash every few minutes. After googling I realized its because I am loading the images in the main thread. What is the right way to load the images. Do I need to use async / Future here. If so, how?

```
 List lstUsers = [
{
 "id": "p1",
 "name": "John Doe",
 "age": "44",
 "imageUrl": [
  "assets/images/anastasia-vityukova-unsplash-blackandwhiteimage.png",
  "assets/images/anastasia-vityukova-unsplash.png",
],
"profession": "Financial Consultant"
},
{
 "id": "p2",
 "name": "John Doe 2",
 "age": "42",
 "imageUrl": [
   "assets/images/good-faces-hiba-unsplash-blackandwhiteimage.png",
   "assets/images/good-faces-hiba-unsplash.jpg",
 ],
 "profession": "Financial Consultant"
 }
];
```

EDIT: It wasn't crashing till I used only one image url; meaning the image url was just another key like the other properties. Now that I have included multiple images, it crashes.

Comment: Have you actually read the following docs? [Adding assets and images](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images) and [display images from the internet
](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/network-image)? Also: where are your images located?

Comment: can you include sample data from `lsUsers` ?

Comment: I have added the code. Images are in the assets folder. lstUsers is stored in a normal data file as data (list).

Comment: can you add your log when your app crashes, as I read from your post, the image is loading but the app is getting crashed? Going through the log can help detect the real issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `AssetImage` alternate and see if the problem persists,

```
...
//IMAGE (and Name Overlay)
Container(
  width: screenWidth,
  height: screenHeight,
  child: Image.asset(
    lstUsers[index]["imageUrl"][0],
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
),
...
```

Comment: No I am loading the images from the assets folder, offline. I mentioned it in the first line of the question.

Comment: Well, then your code should work fine. Provide what `lstUsers[index]["imageUrl"][0]` is.

Comment: Updated question, please see.

Comment: Have you put the location of the images in `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: Yes,  the images are loading fine. It's just that the app crashes after some time (while the images are still showing fine).

Comment: That's weird. I don't think the image might be doing something like that. Check for bugs in other parts of your code.

Comment: Logcat shows "2021-10-02 16:24:12.262 14078-14121/? E/FMQ: grantorIdx must be less than 3", no other errors.

Comment: Give my updated answer a shot and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `assets` from `assets/images/anastasia-vityukova-unsplash-blackandwhiteimage.png,`

Like `images/anastasia-vityukova-unsplash-blackandwhiteimage.png`.

**Demo output with structure, Flutter 2.5.0**
[image]

Here are details about [assets-and-images](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#from-packages).

Does it solve the issue?

Comment: This would be required if the images weren't loading at all. The images are loading fine. It's just that the app crashes after some time (while the images are still showing fine).

Comment: can you include full `Container` widget.

Comment: updated, please see.

Comment: are you looping through images? and how you are doing that? and how you are getting `context` inside `getCard`

Comment: I am yet to do that, I will eventually loop through images but for now, I am only taking the first one as shown in the code. The context is not really needed but its coming from here: Widget build(BuildContext context)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a problem with the emulator; I ran it on a device and it was working fine.